# Forgotten Password script with PDO (decrypt needed)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, password-hash

I have maybe a litle stupid ask... I am doing a forgotten password script (to login system of course) but i am stucked. I created a code (it´s working, yeah !) with a special ID, but i can´t decrypt it... Can you please help me ?

Here is my function of creating special ID :

Recovery_Script.php

```
<?php

include "pdo.php"; if(isset($_POST["submit"]) AND isset($_POST["ForgotPassword"])) {

$email = $_POST["ForgotPassword"];
// Check to see if a user exists with this e-mail
$sql = "SELECT email FROM account WHERE email=:email";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$email));
$items = $stmt->fetchAll();
$db = null;
 foreach($items as $data){
       if($data["email"] == $email){
        // Create a unique salt. This will never leave PHP unencrypted.
        $salt = "498#2D83B631%3800EBD!801600D*7E3CC13";

        // Create the unique user password reset key
        $password = hash('sha256', $salt.$email);

        // Create a url which we will direct them to reset their password
        $pwrurl = "http://student.sps-prosek.cz/~kocvaja14/Project/SelfMade/templates/script/recovery_password.php?q=".$password;

        // Mail them their key
        $mailbody = "Dobrý den,\n\nJestli tento email nepatří vám, prosím, ignorujte jej. Byla vytvořena žádost o obnovení hesla na webové stránce http://student.sps-prosek.cz/~kocvaja14/SelfMade/\n\nPro obnovení hesla klikněte na odkaz níže. \n\nThanks,\nThe Administration";
        mail($email, "http://student.sps-prosek.cz/~kocvaja14/Project/SelfMade/index.php - Password Reset", $mailbody);
        echo "Your password recovery key has been sent to your e-mail address.";

} else
    echo "No user with that e-mail address exists.";  
      } }?>
```

And now i need create file, where i will decrypt this ID ($password). But i can´t do it (cuz i have low knowledge about this stuff). Can you help me with it please ? Thank you !

Comment: Explain *"but i can´t decrypt it"* for us please. Btw, hashes are one-way, in case you want to build a cow from ground meat.

Comment: A sha256 hash _cannot_ be decrypted. It is a one-way hash, not a reversibly encrypted string.  Hashes produce the same hashed string for a given input, and so are used to compare if an input string when hashed with the same algorithm matches the hash you have stored.

Comment: *Of course* you can't "decrypt" a hashed password.  That's *the point*.  Allow the user to reset the password, but you should *never* be able to retrieve the original one.

Comment: If you ever find out a way to do this, remind me NOT to be a member on your site.

Comment: I know, but crypting there an email adress... and i need some identification of user (i must know, who wanted to create new password). In that $password is HASH , RANDOM NUMBERS, EMAIL (there is not true password)

Comment: @XxGhostCZ: I can't make any sense of that last comment.  But the fact remains that hashed passwords *can not* be recovered.  That's the entire point of hashing them.  You're storing user passwords correctly, don't change that.  But do change this requirement to recover the original, because that should not be allowed.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you @David3 Can I somehow send a cookie file via mail ? (Cuz i just need some ID of user, who wanted use recovery password...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to decrypt a sha-hashed value.

What you will need to do is abandon the idea of a password *recovery*, but instead construct a **password reset** system.

One method of doing this is something like so:

1. In your user table, add a column for "reset_hash" (a nice long hashed string)
2. When the user requests a password reset, build a hashed value and store it in their record.  Then, in the e-mail, send a link that includes that "reset_hash" as part of the url.
3. When the user follows the url, check the hash exists in the user table.  If so, present a form in which the user can **change** their password.

Additional precautions you should consider might including using a NONCE, and validating the NONCE which is one way you can cause the link to expire after X hours (NONCEs are only valid for a period of time).